# Connecting to database with Entity Framework: "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred..."

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a console application where I am trying to connect to a database using Entity Framework.

I have connected to the `(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB` server in Visual Studio and created a database `BabyNamesTest`

In VisualStudio I have a class library project as the data layer with a context `NameContext` defined like this:

```
public class NameContext : DbContext
{
    public NameContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<BabyName> BabyNames { get; set; }
}
```

I copied the connection string from Server Explorer & added it like this in `app.config` in the **data layer class library project.** <---- is this the problem??

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>

  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=BabyNamesTest;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

**Edit:** I also have a simple `BabyName` model defined with 2 properties

I have Enabled Migrations in package manager console, added a Migration but when I try to `Update-Database` I'm getting the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I don't understand why this is happening as I can see the database in Server Explorer?

I did try setting `NameContext` with  `base("name=DefaultConnection")` but that didn't work

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: in the `configSections` i think `EntityFramework` related configuration is missing.

Comment: @Venky what should that look like?

Comment: something like ` <section name="entityFramework" 
       type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" /> `  depending on the version of entity framework you are using..

Comment: Also, you need to make sure `BabyNamesTest` database exists already in you local db. EF will not create database on `update-database` command. It expects database to exist already.

Comment: @Venky the database exists....

Comment: @Venky I am getting the same error when I add config sections: `<configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>`

Comment: replace `Defaultconnection` name with `NameContext` in web.config and remove `base("DefaultConnection")`. EF should pick the connection string based on the name of the context automatically.

Comment: Also, i would remove all attributes from connection string except, `Data Source, Initial Catalog and Integrated Security`. Try removing everything else.

Comment: I am not feeling right about `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` name. Usually for local databases  it will be something like `(localdb)\11.0  or 12.0` depending on the version installed.

Comment: Ohh.. i missed the point that you are using `app.config` . EF cannot read connection string from `app.config` . You need to add connection string to `web.config` of the host project where this class library being used.

Comment: This is a console application - can you please do an answer for me?

Comment: If any of the above things worked for you then i can add it as answer. Which one you want me to put in answer.

Comment: "EF cannot read connection string from app.config" - of course it can! In fact, that's the default behavior and also used in pretty much all tutorials. Also, the localDb instance is named upon installing, so the name should not matter. To OP: Does the Sql Server Service run? What happens when you try to open a DbConnection using the connection string consisting only on Data Source, Initial Catalog and Trusted Connection/Integrated Security?